# Clicking on a checkbox toggles other checkbox at times

Tags: html, css, checkbox

So I got 5 `checkbox`. All below one another. They have been made using `svg` and `polyline`. When I click on the label of each checkbox, it toggles the correct one, but when I click on the image of the checkbox, at times it toggles the incorrect box!

```
.cbx {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cbx span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.cbx span:first-child {
  position: relative;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transform: scale(1);
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #9098A9;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.cbx span:first-child svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 2px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.cbx span:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #506EEC;
  display: block;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.cbx span:last-child {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.cbx:hover span:first-child {
  border-color: #506EEC;
}

.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child {
  background: #506EEC;
  border-color: #506EEC;
  animation: wave 0.4s ease;
}
.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child:before {
  transform: scale(3.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

@keyframes wave {
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}
```

The html

```
<div class="ax-cb-div">
  <input class="inp-cbx" id="1" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
  <label for="1" class="cbx"><span>
    <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
      <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </svg></span><span>Checkbox number 1</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="ax-cb-div">
  <input class="inp-cbx" id="2" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
  <label for="2" class="cbx"><span>
    <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
      <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </svg></span><span>Checkbox number 2</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="ax-cb-div">
  <input class="inp-cbx" id="3" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
  <label for="3" class="cbx"><span>
    <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
      <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </svg></span><span>Checkbox number 3</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="ax-cb-div">
  <input class="inp-cbx" id="4" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
  <label for="4" class="cbx"><span>
    <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
      <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </svg></span><span>Checkbox number 4</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Select checkbox 1, 2, 3, 4. Then click on checkbox 3 to uncheck it. Checkbox 4 gets unchecked instead. Upon clicking again on checkbox 3, it gets unchecked.

Link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/varunagarwal315/pen/oVOQGr)

Answer (score 1):

because transform: scale(3.5) on check expand it's size and cover other checkbox that's why..

> ```
> .inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child:before {
>   transform: scale(1); // set scale to it's actual size instead of 3.5
>   opacity: 0;
>   transition: all 0.6s ease;
> }
> ```

```css
.cbx {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cbx span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.cbx span:first-child {
  position: relative;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transform: scale(1);
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #9098A9;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.cbx span:first-child svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 2px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.cbx span:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #506EEC;
  display: block;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.cbx span:last-child {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.cbx:hover span:first-child {
  border-color: #506EEC;
}

.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child {
  background: #506EEC;
  border-color: #506EEC;
  animation: wave 0.4s ease;
}
.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

@keyframes wave {
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ax-cb-div">
  <input class="inp-cbx" id="1" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
  <label for="1" class="cbx"><span>
    <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
      <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </svg></span><span>Checkbox number 1</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="ax-cb-div">
  <input class="inp-cbx" id="2" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
  <label for="2" class="cbx"><span>
    <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
      <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </svg></span><span>Checkbox number 2</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="ax-cb-div">
  <input class="inp-cbx" id="3" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
  <label for="3" class="cbx"><span>
    <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
      <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </svg></span><span>Checkbox number 3</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="ax-cb-div">
  <input class="inp-cbx" id="4" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
  <label for="4" class="cbx"><span>
    <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
      <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </svg></span><span>Checkbox number 4</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Will test this out, but I think you may be right! Will accept once I have edited it on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Adding pointer-events none to the span seem like working fix

```
.cbx span {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

https://codepen.io/chemicalbr/pen/KEYbgG

Comment: Looks like it but won't removing pointer events stop any clicking on that `span` element?

Comment: yes it will remove registration of any pointer events on the span but you obviously do not need them on the span but on the label in order to toggle checked state on the input.

Comment: Yes but the span is within the label, so won't removing the pointer on the span affect a section of the label?

Comment: No, if the span  is over label the click will be absorbed by the label itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value tag.

```
<input id="1" value="test" ../>
<input id="3" value="test" ../>
```

[MDN Web docs - Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#Value)

Comment: The animation of the checkbox is what I am referring to. I am facing no issues in getting data and list of checkbox using jquery. Click on the `codepen` link and recreate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change transform property value to 1.5

```
.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child:before {
   transform: scale(1.5);
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to `.cbx span:first-child:before` style. It's the animation that causes the problem.

In `.cbx span:first-child:before` we are scaling the `content:""` from `scale(0)` and `opacity:1` to `scale(3.5)` and `opacity:0` respectively. So actually we are just hiding that object with opacity which means object will be there and clickable. That's why we need to add `pointer-events:none` to `.cbx span:first-child:before` style.

To test it, just check the 4th checkbox and inspect it with `.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child:before` style. Change opacity from 0 to `opacity:1`. You will see something like below.

[image]

In above image, you can see the `span:before` of 4th checkbox covers the 3rd checkbox. And it's clickable. That's why when you click on 3rd checkbox, it actually clicks on 4th one.

See the Snippet below.

```css
.cbx {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cbx span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.cbx span:first-child {
  position: relative;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transform: scale(1);
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #9098A9;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.cbx span:first-child svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 2px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.cbx span:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #506EEC;
  display: block;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.cbx span:last-child {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.cbx:hover span:first-child {
  border-color: #506EEC;
}

.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child {
  background: #506EEC;
  border-color: #506EEC;
  animation: wave 0.4s ease;
}
.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
.inp-cbx:checked + .cbx span:first-child:before {
  transform: scale(3.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

@keyframes wave {
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ax-cb-div">
  <input class="inp-cbx" id="1" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
  <label for="1" class="cbx"><span>
    <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
      <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </svg></span><span>Checkbox number 1</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="ax-cb-div">
  <input class="inp-cbx" id="2" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
  <label for="2" class="cbx"><span>
    <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
      <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </svg></span><span>Checkbox number 2</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="ax-cb-div">
  <input class="inp-cbx" id="3" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
  <label for="3" class="cbx"><span>
    <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
      <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </svg></span><span>Checkbox number 3</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="ax-cb-div">
  <input class="inp-cbx" id="4" type="checkbox" style="display: none;"/>
  <label for="4" class="cbx"><span>
    <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
      <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
    </svg></span><span>Checkbox number 4</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain how does the animation cause the problem? Like why does a click on a checkbox/svg causes the one below it to trigger first?

Comment: We are just changing the opacity from 1 to 0 and also scaling it from 0 to 3.5. So the object is not visible but its there and clickable. I have added detailed explanation in my answer. Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Does that make sense, @VarunAgarwal?